# Firefox 78.0.2 snap saved logins (about:logins) empty

Tags: login, firefox, snap, sync

After the latest snap refresh of Firefox 78.0.2 the about:logins page is empty.

The saved logins file still exists (logins.json) and I can save new entries.  When I select the Firefox Menu > Logins & Passwords the Firefox Locksafe logo appears on the about:logins page but the login list is empty.

If I go the my bookmarks list and select a site (eg ebay) and click the site sign-in all my logins options for the site appear and can be used to login.

I use Firefox sync and I can view the logins on the synced devices. I'm running 16.04 vanilla.

Any clues would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu.Can you see anything special in the terminal output when you open firefox from terminal? Or from ```gnome-logs```? You can search for **firefox** there.

Comment: Hi I ran the following commands:  
`journalctl --system -f`  ;
`snap list`  ;
`firefox`  ;
The results are here https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gT6sDTNFS6/

Nothing jumped out at me.